# Client to Server Authentication for SharePoint Online REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am looking for answers if SharePoint online supports client-to-server authentication. My use case is to access Sharepoint REST API via pure JS with no server involved.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I believe you can use [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) in order to have a communication with the SharePoint REST API from the client.

Mentioned below are few resources which might help you in understanding this method and implement in your solution.

If you have angular application then you can use [adal-angular - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular)
If you have react application then you can use [react-adal - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal)

You can also refer to the article from Andrew Connel on how to use ADAL JS with Angular to communicate with Sharepoint.
[ADAL JS & CORS with O365 APIs (Files & SharePoint)](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/adal-js-cors-with-o365-apis-files-sharepoint)